# First platformer enemy to stun players by jumping?

Tags: gaming-history

In platformer games, there’s a fairly common trope/mechanic of an unusually heavy enemy that, when they land after jumping, stuns the player if they are on the ground. Examples include Sledge Brothers and at least one of the Koopa kids from Super Mario Brothers 3, and the earliest one I can come up with is Guts Man from Mega Man 1 (1987). I’m wondering if that was the first, or if there are even earlier examples.

The precise mechanic I’m looking for: When the entity lands on the ground, if the player is on the ground, they are unable to move, but if the player is in the air, they are unaffected. If there’s an early example that isn’t strictly an “enemy”, I’m still interested.